# NamedQuery returns nothing

Tags: sql, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink, named-query

I have written a namedQuery in my Entity class as  @NamedQuery(name="Place.findByPlaceCode", query="select p from Place p where p.Code = :placeCode")

I execute the named query with the following :

```
List<Country> result = getEntityManager()
            .createNamedQuery("Place.findByPlaceCode")
            .setParameter("placeCode", placeCode)
            .getResultList();       
return processResult(result);
```

However, it is returning nothing .

If I write an SQL query in the database it runs fine but this namedQuery is not working.
I tried setting the parameter manually to the value "Beach" and also tried "Beach " to check if it was the whitespaces causing the issue but it did'nt make any difference.
How should I check the values returned by this query ?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same database/schema etc? Set EclipseLink logging to finest to see where it is connecting and the SQL it is generating using <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>. You might also try turning parameter binding off for this query using query.setHint(QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS, HintValues.FALSE) to see if it is a driver/database string handling issue.